# css dashed line next to div?

Tags: css

I want to achieve this dashed line with pure css

[image]

My solution is to use the :after pseudo element to draw the dashed line, is there another way to achieve this? without using pseudo elements?
I want to use one simple class to achieve this, the width of the dashed line can be static..

Comment: Usually I prefer pure CSS solutions, but pay attention to dashed borders: they are rendered **very** different in many browsers. Are you sure you want to continue on this path?

Comment: "better" in which terms?

Comment: Please show what you've already tried in a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: The display of the elements must be carried by DOM, must use ::after or dom

Comment: When you say "pure CSS", do you mean restricting yourself to a single HTML element? If you want to do this all in one HTML element, I don't think you can do it without pseudo classes. CSS simply doesn't have a way to render what you want. If you are good with adding HTML elements, then there are a lot of ways to do this. Please clarify!

Comment: @cdpautsch There are ways to do it without pseudos ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider background coloration to achieve this:

```css
.box {
  padding:5px; 
  border-right:100px solid transparent; /* The same as the width of the line */
  background:
    /*the borders*/
    linear-gradient(red,red) top   /100% 2px padding-box,
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 2px padding-box,
    linear-gradient(red,red) left  /2px 100% padding-box,
    linear-gradient(red,red) right /2px 100% padding-box,
    /*the dashed line*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0px 3px,transparent 3px 5px) right center/100px 2px border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  max-width:250px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 Some text here
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
 Some long long text here with some wrapping
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a shadow. set different shadows, overlapping, and changing between red and white.

```css
.test {
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    border: solid 2px red;
    box-shadow: 15px 0px 0px -10px red,
                20px 0px 0px -10px white,
                25px 0px 0px -10px red,
                30px 0px 0px -10px white,
                35px 0px 0px -10px red,
                40px 0px 0px -10px white,
                45px 0px 0px -10px red,
                50px 0px 0px -10px white,
                55px 0px 0px -10px red,
                60px 0px 0px -10px white,
                65px 0px 0px -10px red,
                70px 0px 0px -10px white,
                75px 0px 0px -10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
Whatever text
</div>
```

Comment: Nice trick the negative spread, didn't know it but worth to note that the height is important for this trick. (as a side note, your code is not working on fiferox so better switch to inline-block as min-content is still not supported)